# When drilling down, how to retrieve the parent?

Tags: iccube-reporting

In a dimension I have 
1st layer > 2nd layer

I display a chart with values from 1st layer and drilling down to 2nd layer when clicked on.
Once clicked, the graph displays value for the children, so 2nd layer only.

How do I retrieve and display the 1st layer that was clicked on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charts can generate iccube-events for a couple of js events (I guess here on row click).

Check the image below :

[image]

Edit:

For a bar chart, use "On Navigate" event.

[image]
[image]